# AmCharts line chart animation

Tags: javascript, animation, amcharts

Is it possible to animate a line chart in AmCharts in a way that shows the line being drawn (either by connecting the bullets or drawing the line sequentially left to right)?

I've played around with the `startDuration`, `startEffect` and `sequencedAnimation` properties but all of the options seem to animate the entire line as a whole, either sliding it down from the top or bouncing it upon entry. It's better than no animation and is perfect for column/bar graphs but it looks somewhat odd and unnatural for a line graph.

[Here is the relevant documentation for AmCharts](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation you linked to, http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#startEffect, the only effects that are available at this point in time are...

- easeOutSine
- easeInSine
- elastic
- bounce

These are all bounce or slide in type graphs, they do not currently offer a join the dots type effect that you are wanting as yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can animate your amchart in a way that it draws.
You do that with CSS:

```
#chartdiv{
width       : 100%;
height      : 500px;
}

.amcharts-graph-g1 { //g1 is the id of your graph
  stroke-dasharray: 500%;
  -webkit-animation: am-draw 5s;
  animation: am-draw 5s;
}

@keyframes am-draw {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
    }
}
```

Check out this link: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/css-animations/